# Cat awk command additional code implementation

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, terminal, awk

I want to understand how to use awk cat command because I think to do not understand

In [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64735679/3861070) he suggest me to use his code

You should process `g2.txt` first like this:

```
cat join2.awk

BEGIN {
  OFS=FS=";"
}
ARGIND == 1 {
   map[$2] = ($2 in map ? map[$2] OFS : "") $1
   next
}
{
   r = $0;
   for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i)
      if ($i in map)
         r = r OFS map[$i]
   $0 = r
}
1
```

Then use it as:

```
awk -f join2.awk g2.txt g1.txt
```

But I don't understand how to use and implement this command `cat join2.awk` with his addition code.
Usualy, from command line, I use `awk -f join2.sh g2.txt g1.txt`, why `join2.awk`? (I use awk under windows)

This is my original code, join2.sh

```
#! /usr/bin/awk  -f

BEGIN {
  OFS=FS=";"
  C=0;
}
{
  if (ARGIND == 1) {
     X = $NF
     T0[$NF] = C++
     $NF = ""
     if (T1[X]) {
        T1[X] = T1[X] $0
     } else {
        T1[X] = $0
     }
  } else {
     X = $NF
     T0[$NF] = C++
     $NF = ""
     if (T2[X]) {
        T2[X] = T2[X] $0
     } else {
        T2[X] = $0
     }
  }
}

END {
  for (X in T0) {
    # concatenate T1[X] and X, since T1[X] ends with ";"
    print T1[X]  X, T2[X]
  }
}
```

I don't understand how to use **his** additional code. Do I have to integrate it into mine? Do I need to create another script?
What does it mean "*You should process `g2.txt` first like this*?

**How to execute this code?** Can you show me, please? Because `awk -f join2.awk g2.txt g1.txt` is not sufficient, I need to find a way to use before `cat join2.awk` and I don't understand how implement his code and execute it

```
cat join2.awk
    
    BEGIN {
      OFS=FS=";"
    }
    ARGIND == 1 {
       map[$2] = ($2 in map ? map[$2] OFS : "") $1
       next
    }
    {
       r = $0;
       for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i)
          if ($i in map)
             r = r OFS map[$i]
       $0 = r
    }
    1
```

SOLVED:
[image]

Comment: In this case `cat join2.awk` means that when you invoke `cat join2.awk` in a *shell*, `cat` will show you the content of `join2.awk` and it will look like everything that follows. So the actual content of the file is *after* `cat join2.awk`.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski mm.. but can I use Command Prompt under Windows or I need to use a shell from linux? ok, I understand that I need to type `cat join2.awk` but I don't understand where or what should to to with his code. Why he write me that code? How to use it? I know how use my code but not his. In my windows folder I have `join2.sh` and not `join2.awk`. However join2.sh is my code but he write me another code

Comment: I don't understand how to use with cat command his code  `BEGIN {
      OFS=FS=";"
    }
    ARGIND == 1 {
       map[$2] = ($2 in map ? map[$2] OFS : "") $1
       next
    }
    {
       r = $0;
       for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i)
          if ($i in map)
             r = r OFS map[$i]
       $0 = r
    }
    1`

Comment: Sigh… You don't need `cat` but you need to know what it does. *If* you had `cat` and used it on the file (`cat join2.awk`) then it would show you the content of the file. The other user placed the content after `cat join2.awk`. `cat join2.awk` is a command and everything that follows is its *result*. From the result you learn what the content of the file should be. I admit this is misleading, unless you know what `cat` does. You were told to use the file like this: `awk -f join2.awk g2.txt g1.txt`.

Comment: I understand https://i.imgur.com/gWXprrw.png